# Name stacked bars after legend entry on Pandas/Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, charts, stacked

I have a stacked bar chart that works really well for what I'm looking for. My problem is handling the labels.

I can label every single stacked bar after its value (number), but I'm looking to label it after its name (on the legend).

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

ps.: Unfortunately I can't post images yet.

```
I have something like this:
    ####
    #15#
    ####
    oooo        ####
    oooo        #35#
    o55o        ####
    oooo        ####
    oooo        o12o


And need like this:
    ####
    #### A
    ####
    oooo        ####
    oooo B      #### A
    oooo        ####
    oooo        oooo B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Dex answer I came up with a solution.
Using patches, it will get every single bar from the chart. The bars are ordenated by rows. So if you have a 4x3 dataframe:

```
   zero  um  dois
0     a   b     c
1     d   e     f
2     g   h     i
3     j   k     l
```

bars.patches will have each column after the other: [a,d,g,j,b,e,h,k,c,f,i,l]

So, every 4 items (rows), it restarts. To do that, we can use the the mod function (%) based on the number of rows on the df:

```
i % len(df.index)  == 0   #moves position counter to the next column name
```

The code ended up like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Some data
x  = np.array(['zero', 'um', 'dois'])
y = np.array([[3, 4, 8],[2, 2, 4],[6, 7, 8]])

df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns = x)

print(df)

   zero  um  dois
0     3   4     8
1     2   2     4
2     6   7     8



title = 'Chart Title'
bars = df.plot.bar(ax = ax, stacked = True, title = title, legend = False)

plt.xlabel('x axis label')

pos = -1
for i, bar in enumerate(bars.patches):     #runs through every single bar on the chart
    if i % len(df.index) == 0:             #based on lenght of the index, gets which label 
        pos += 1                           #to use from the columns. Returning to the 
                                           #first after completing a row
        
    xloc = bar.get_x()                     
    yloc = bar.get_y() + bar.get_height() / 2
    if bar.get_height() > 30:
        ax.annotate(str(df.columns[pos]), xy = (xloc, yloc), va='center', ha='left')

                        #df.columns[pos] will get the correct column name
```

So, no matter the size of the dataframe, it will plot the column names next to the bars

chart example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iHau.png

Answer (score 1):

I've written a short example, see the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some data
x  = np.array([0, 1, 2])
y1 = np.array([3, 4, 1])
y2 = np.array([2, 2, 4])

# label text
label_y1 = 'y1'
label_y2 = 'y2'

# Create the base plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bars_y1 = ax.bar(x, y1, width=0.5, label=label_y1)
bars_y2 = ax.bar(x, y2, width=0.5, label=label_y2, bottom=y1)

# Function to add labels to the plot
def add_labels(ax, bars, label):
    for bar in bars:
        # Get the desired x and y locations
        xloc = bar.get_x() + 1.05 * bar.get_width()
        yloc = bar.get_y() + bar.get_height() / 2
        
        ax.annotate(label, xy=(xloc, yloc), va='center', ha='left', color=bar.get_facecolor())


# Add the labels in the plot
add_labels(ax, bars_y1, label_y1)
add_labels(ax, bars_y2, label_y2)

plt.show()
```

First of all, I generate some dummy data (`x`, `y1` and `y2`). Then, I define the desired label text (`label_y1` and `label_y2`) and lastly I make the base bar graph using [`Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html). Note that I store the return value from the `Axes.bar` calls, which is a container containing all the bars!

Now, we get to the interesting part. I define a function called `add_labels`. As an input, it takes the Axes of interest, a container with all the bars and the desired label text. In the function body, I loop over all the bars and determine the desired x and y location for the label text. Using these values, I place label text at those coordinates using the [`Axes.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html?highlight=axes%20annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) method. At the end of the script, I simply call the `add_labels` function with the desired arguments to get the following output:

[image: Sample output]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Dex! Thanks a lot for your answer! I've solved it in a different way, but your answer helped me realize what I was missing! Thanks!!!

My problem has some extras requirements such:
- variable number of columns on the dataframe
- number of rows
- available size

So I used the patches from the plot to handle the legend as you can see below